Can we use a canonical question for Pokemon Go system requirements?
Our pokemon-go tag got absolutely smashed with new questions when the game first came out. As such, we have many kinda-related questions about system requirements (screen resolution, RAM, whether specific devices can run the game etc), in various states of open/closed/duplicate.
A lot of the answers are outdated, just from Niantic slowly upping the system requirements over the years, and thus I think it's worth reviewing and duplicating them to one canonical1 question, which can be kept up to date easier, helping future readers find the information they're after.

This is the most generic system requirements question I can find, and given the view count, it's probably our best candidate for a canonical question: Pokemon Go Supported Devices. Full disclosure: I answered it, but the answer is currently out of date2.
Below are the ones I've found over the past couple of days. (I've answered some of them too in the past). I've broken them into general topic areas:

Troubleshooting crashes
The following questions pertain to devices crashing/failing to run the game due to poor performance:

Pokemon go crashes down - RAM issue
Pokémon go technical issues - RAM issue
I CAN install Pokemon Go from Google Play Store but it won't open - Tablet device + RAM
Pokemon GO with Hotspot - Tablet devices specifically without 3/4/5G connectivity
Did the compatibility requirements change? - Tablet device
How do I avoid 'No GPS signal' in Pokemon Go on an iPad with a GPS? - Tablet device

Device-specific
a.k.a. "Can I run it?". Note that all of these specific devices are now majorly out of spec for Pokemon Go:

Can a LG Ice Cream Smart run Pokemon GO?
Will the Samsung Galaxy Nexus run Pokémon Go?
Does the Micromax Spark not support Pokémon go?

Questions about specific requirements
These focus on a specific requirement rather than just generally all requirements. I am personally considering duplicating them to the canoncial as well, but I also understand if people want them kept separate:

Does Pokemon Go have a minimum resolution requirement?
What is the minimum RAM required for Pokemon GO?

iPods and iPads without GPS or Mobile/Cellular Data
This subset of questions are specific to iPods without accurate location data (i.e. location is determined by nearby Wi-Fi rather than GPS). These could have their duplicate lists edited to also link to the system requirements canonical:

I have an iPod Touch 5th gen. Can I play Pokemon Go? - current dupe target for:

Can I download GPS so I can play Pokémon go?
Why is Pokemon go not working?
Pokemon Go On My iPod 5th Gen
Pokemon GO isn't working on my iPod 5g
Why does my character jump around when playing Pokemon Go on an iPod?



This might not be the exhaustive list, so let me know if you come across others that could also be included, or if another question is a better candidate for a canonical.

With all that said, I turn this over to the community at large: Do you think it's a good idea to nominate a canonical here, and mark the rest as a duplicate? Are there any concerns or caveats that I've overlooked?

1 This canonical should be distinct from the one about PC system requirements, given it's a mobile game (and specific to Pokemon Go)
2 I will update the answer before beginning the process of marking other questions as duplicates

You want to have a Q&A to ...... "Catch them all?" I'm 100% ok with this

@Wondercricket yerbanned

You caught my attention! (sorry)

status-completed
All of the above questions (bar one) have been marked as a duplicate of the canonical question: How to check if my device will run Pokemon Go? What devices are supported?, on which I have also updated the answer.
The one that I didn't mark duplicate is How do I avoid 'No GPS signal' in Pokemon Go on an iPad with a GPS? - this is more generally about poor GPS signal, and not necessarily about being incompatible.
